# Many to many table in Laravel with multiple database connections

Tags: laravel, database-connection, relationship

I do have a central database(db2) with users, roles and user_role tables and the standard database for my application.

While connecting to the users and roles works fine with defining the db connections in the model like so:

```
protected $table = 'db2.users';
protected $table = 'db2.roles';
```

I would like to have my user_role table in db2 as well, but how would I define the connection. With a model User_Role? At the moment it only works if I have the user_role table in my standard db connection